# Overlay hyperlinks next to tabitems on tabcontrol

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a tabcontrol with 1-3 tabitems (one is always displayed, the other two are hidden if no objects are defined in the database view model).

To the right of the tabitems, I would like to add a few hyperlink commands.  They do not have to float with the tabitems (location can be static).  However, I can't get them to overlay the tabcontrol and line up with the tabs.

I'd rather not mess with the tabcontrol template - just looking for the easiest way to put the links on top.

Any thoughts?

Comment: "However, I can't get them to overlay the tabcontrol and line up with the tabs." If you post your code that doesn't work.. we could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple, quick, no frills workaround to accomplish your goal;

```
<Grid>
   <TabControl/>
   <Hyperlink/>
   <Hyperlink/>
</Grid>
```

This would allow you to float your Hyperlink objects over top of the TabControl then you can use Alignments & Margins to get them to the exact spot you want in relation to your tabs. Or embed the Hyperlinks in a `StackPanel` or whatever and apply Alignment/Margin to it.

Just make sure to keep their visual tree position correct within a container and voila...

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh duh, I forgot that grids plop items on top of each other when the columns aren't specified.  Thanks for answering such a no-brainer question!  I would up-vote, but I don't have enough rep for that...

Comment: No worries, just glad you got a solution. :)